Django: check if logged in user has made database entry
I am creating an apartment booking homepage and would like to display a "Your Bookings" tab in the nav bar if the logged in user has made a booking. If not, the tab in the nav bar should not be visible. I have tried the below approach but it does not work yet. The logged in user who has made a booking still cannot see the "Your Bookings" tab in the nav bar. Could anyone point out what's missing here?
views.py
def check_if_booking_exists(request):
    current_user = request.user
    booking_exists = Booking.objects.filter(current_user).exists()
    if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.is_superuser and booking_exists:
        return render(
        request, 
        'template/base.html', 
                {
            'current_user': current_user,
            'booking_exists': booking_exists
        }
    )

base.html
{% if booking_exists %}

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle hvr-bounce-in margin-left-right" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-current="page">
              Booking
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink3">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'booking' %}" aria-current="page">Booking Form</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'your-bookings' %}" aria-current="page">Your Bookings</a>
            </div>


I have found a working solution in the meantime by using a context processor.
context_processor.py
from .models import Booking

def booking_exists(request):
    """
    Checks if a logged in guest has made a booking
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        has_booking = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()
    else:
        has_booking = False

    return {
        'booking_exists': has_booking
    }

views.py
def check_if_booking_exists(request):
    """
    Checks if a logged in guest has made a booking
    """
    current_user = request.user
    if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.is_superuser:
        booking_exists = Booking.objects.filter(user=current_user).exists()
    else:
        booking_exists = False

    return {
        'current_user': current_user,
        'booking_exists': booking_exists
    }

base.html
{% if user.is_authenticated and not user.is_superuser and booking_exists %}

settings.py
adding 'home.context_processors.booking_exists', to TEMPLATES under context processors


Please correct the last codeblock, thanks.

I think you are not filtering any particular field in your Booking model. Actually in Django , the filter() method expects an argument showing the field to filter on and the value to filter for.
def check_if_booking_exists(request):
    current_user = request.user
    booking_exists = Booking.objects.filter(user=current_user).exists() 
    if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.is_superuser and booking_exists:
        return render(
            request, 
            'template/base.html', 
            {
                'current_user': current_user,
                'booking_exists': booking_exists
            }
        )



I'm not sure what you're getting at. In the solution I found and posted as answer to my post, it says "filter(user=current_user)"
